# Interesting behavior with background-color and border-radius

Tags: html, css

Interesting behavior with border-radius and background-color

I have the following html:

```html
 <div class="block">
     <div class="button">
        hover me, baby!
     </div>
 </div>
```

and CSS:

```css
.block {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

when i hover over element i see this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z52KQ.png)

I want to ask if that is an expected behavior? Because in my head it isn't. I have two elements a parent and a child. With the same sizes. With the same border-radius. You can inspect elements and confirm that they have the same width and height. But anyway once i hover over inner element i see red little borders of parent element even tho i dont have any border.

here's the code [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-qgvqj2?file=/styles.css:0-195)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a sort of edge effect where the system is having to decide how to map CSS pixels to screen pixels. There are several screen pixels to one CSS pixel on modern devices and sometimes a screen pixel can get ‘left behind’, hence the red dots you are seeing.

You may find these come and go as you zoom in and out.

A simple if slightly hacks way round this is to expand the child very slightly when it is hovered. Using transform scale this won’t affect the positioning of anything else.

```css
.block {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
    <div class="block">
      <div class="button">
        hover me, baby!
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.button:hover {  
background-color: white;
border: white solid 1px;
border-radius: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is because you are adding background color to the wrapper div `.block` but you are applying background color when hove to another element which is `.button`

So when you hover the `.button` it changes `.button` div background to white but the background color for `.block` remains the same

to avoid this I recommend to move this code from `.block`:

```
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 8px;
```

and added to your `.button` which is the element that you change their property when hover

the full code will be

```
.block {
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That is happening because the border-radius on your button is the same value as the border-radius of your block element with the red background. You can resolve this by removing the border-radius of the button or adding the hover selector to the block element.

Option 1:

```css
.block {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Removed border-radius on button */
.button {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Another simple example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="button">
        hover me, baby!
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Option 2:

```css
.block {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

/* Changed class to .block for hover selector */
.block:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Another simple example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="button">
        hover me, baby!
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).